# How to display output in a simple dockerized Python application?

Tags: python, matplotlib, docker

I just started using docker and am still struggling a bit in it's usage. I have a python simple python application that uses Matplotlib to generate some simple graphs. I currently have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2

COPY requirements.txt /    
RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt   
COPY my_code.py /

CMD [ "python", "./my_code.py" ]
```

This however generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fraud_detection_sample_code.py", line 161, in <module>
    plt.figure(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1820, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

What would be the best way to solve this? Is it even possible with my approach?

Comment: Docker is not meant such use-cases.

Comment: How would you, in that case, dockerize an application like this? Or is it simply not possible?

Comment: The thing is that docker is ment for deployment and scaling your application across multiple VMs when the user base grows. Dockerizing python script that just showing output via command line just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Isn't docker also ideal to share projects between multiple developers? This is an example of a python project that is used in university, it needs to be executed and modified by hundreds of students. Are there other techniques that are more suitable for a certain situation?

Comment: I think good documentation would do the job better. And if you want to automate setup write a simple shell script or make a setup.py. Don't mess with docker for this usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Could you test this?

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix your_image_name
```

It worked for me in a similar project. Idea from [here](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/)